# NSStackView Memory Leak?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am running Xcode 8 on macOS Sierra  and have noticed that the NSStackView is showing leaks in Instruments. A simple app with two label controls embedded in a StackView will do the trick of generating the leak.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is this expected behaivour?

Michael